# OpenSSH 6.8p1 Cant use multiple AuthenticationMethods

Tags: openssh

I am running openssh 6.8p1 and I am trying to configure multiple authenticaton methods

Its works with just

**AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password"**

but not with

**AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password keyboard-interactive:pam"**

However sshd will not start. It gives me the error msg:

**Unknown authentication method "password keyboard-interactive" in list**

Here is the output of /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 667
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 667
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:1 setting Protocol 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:2 setting SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:3 setting PermitRootLogin no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:5 setting AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys 
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:6 setting RevokedKeys /etc/ssh/revoked_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:8 setting AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password keyboard-interactive:pam,password"
Unknown authentication method "password keyboard-interactive" in list
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 8: invalid authentication method list.
```

and here is my sshd config

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin no

AuthorizedKeysFile      /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
RevokedKeys             /etc/ssh/revoked_keys
AuthenticationMethods       "publickey,password keyboard-interactive:pam"

PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

X11Forwarding yes
Banner /etc/motd
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the double quotes from around the argument to **AuthenticationMethods**,
then it started to work.

Comment: Please mark this as your answer